# Remove all text in text area that's between two positions

Tags: jquery

I know how to retrieve the cursor position with `$('textarea').prop('selectionStart') //=> 3` and `$('textarea').prop('selectionEnd') //=> 9`.

How should I write a function to remove text between positions 3 and 9?

This is how I'm deleting one character:

```
function replace_character(position, characters, a){
    var original_content = $('textarea').val(),
        new_content = original_content.substr(0, position) + characters + original_content.substr(position, original_content.length);

    $('textarea').val(new_content)
};
```

This may seem verbose but I'm using that function for replacing a character with a different character as well, so it's not a bloated as it may seem.

Anyway, how should I delete all text between two positions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the start of the value to selectionStart as your first chunk, then concatenate on the selectionEnd to end of value as the second chunk:

```
function replace_character() {
    var subject = $('textarea'); // should this be a little more specific??
    var original_content = subject.val().trim();
    var new_content = original_content.substr(0, subject.prop('selectionStart')) + original_content.substr(subject.prop('selectionEnd'));
    subject.val(new_content);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LYLBh/